# Div width not 100% of free space

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a row of divs which are vertically centered. I do not want to use HTML tables or CSS's table-cell etc.

The width of the first child div will not be 100%. It should be. I have no idea...

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px"><!-- this is not 100% but it should be -->
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to 1...

      <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px"><!-- this is not 100% but it should be -->
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to 2...

      <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 100% value is 100% of the parent's width. See the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 100% value is 100% of the parent's width. See the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width).

You need to add the width on the child's div:

```html
<div>
  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px"><!-- this is not 100% but it should be -->
    <div style="width:100%; display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to 1...

      <div style="float: right;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px"><!-- this is not 100% but it should be -->
    <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to 2...

      <div style="float: right;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to have those hyperlinks on the right hand side.

Comment: Almost perfect, but now we need a scrollbar :)

Comment: It's your border that makes the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it IS 100%:

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px;background-color:pink"><!-- this IS 100% as it should be -->
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to...

      <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe that's what you actually looking for?:

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="clear:both;padding:2px"><!-- this IS 100% as it should be -->
    <div style="display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;background-color:#D0D5E6;border: 10px solid #D0D5E6;">
      Go to...

      <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:right;">
        <a href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looking more closely at your code I may assume that actually you are trying to achieve this:

```html
<div style="padding:10px;background-color:#D0D5E6;">
  <div>Go to...<a style="float:right" href="goto.html">Go &raquo;</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The pink background is your "child div". I set the background to pink so you can see that it's taking 100% width actually.

Comment: Yes but the div with the background color #D0D5E6 is not 100% of the width of the pink div. It should be.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Display inline-block doesn't mean 100% of the width.

Comment: Yes, I see. Anyway, I would like to be it that way. I should replace inline-block but I do not know better ways if I still want to vertically align my texts.

Comment: Set width: 100% for that div then.

Comment: @xms You might want to look at flex if you want content to fill responsively.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Mike.